# Can I install an old java plugin?

Tags: java, browser, applet, signed-applet, appletviewer

Is there any way to install an old version of the Java plugin in any of my browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome or Opera)? I want to be able to test a set of applets without digitally signing them, but Oracle's crazy signing policy is making it impossible. The appletviewer won't cut it for me (the applets interact with each other and with JavaScript on the same page). It seems to be impossible to get an applet signed without paying some money to someone somewhere along the line, and I really can't be bothered with that...

I still have an old JDK 1.5 installed in addition to a JDK 1.8; is there any way of convincing a browser to use it? Maybe an old browser, if I can find one somewhere? (I have a copy of Netscape 3 somewhere, but that might be a bit *too* old...)

Any suggestions welcomed, except for "sign the applets"!

Comment: *"It seems to be impossible to get an applet signed without paying some money to someone somewhere along the line, and I really can't be bothered with that..."* So... what are you planning to do at time of deployment to the general public?

Comment: I'm not planning to deploy to the general public. This is a tool for my own personal use.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there are several ways to test your applets:

1. Sign your applet with a self signed certificate and add that certificate to the certificate store (java and browser)
2. Get a trial certificate of one of the many officals CAs and sign your applets
3. Decrease the security slider in the java system properties - especially if you have an older java version installed (e.g. Java 1.7.17 which is available in the java download archive at oracle)
4. Test your webpage/applets with different browsers. Especially the IE has not such strict rules regarding applet security like chrome or firefox (they deactivate the plugin by default etc.)

But please note, those solutions are only for local testing and not a productive environment...

Answer (score 0):

Try with enable only java 1.5 in table from "Java Control Panel > Java > View"

For Linux type `jcontrol` in terminal. 
 For Windows search in control panel for Java configurations.

It should be start Java 1.5 for applets.